# Javascript - Link Name Changing with restrictions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the name of a link, however, I have some restrictions. The link is placed in code that looks like this:

```
<li class='time'> 
<a href="#time">Review Time</a> 
<img alt="Styled" src="blah" /> 
</li>
```

Basically, I have a class name to work with. I'm not allowed to edit anything in these lines, and I only have a header/footer to write Javascript / CSS in. **I'm trying to get *Review Time* to show up as *Time Review***, for example.

I know that I can hide it by using .time{ display: hide} in CSS, but I can't figure out a way to replace the text. The text is also a link, as shown. I've tried a variety of replace functions and such in JS, but I'm either doing it wrong, or it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This homework or for a job application?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the child elements of the li that has the class name you are looking for, and then change the innerHTML of the anchor tags that you find.

For example:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i = 0, j = elements.length; i<j; i++){
        elements[i].innerHTML = "Time Review";
    }
```

Of course, this assumes that there is one element named "time" on the page. You would also need to be careful about checking for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Split the words on space, reverse the order, put back together.

```
var j = $('li.time > a');
var t = j.text();
var a = t.split(' ');
var r = a.reverse();
j.text(r.join(' '));
```

This could have some nasty consequences in a multilingual situation.

Comment: Then I suppose we could substitute the appropriate javascript selection. Really wouldn't change the logic. I just prefer not to write more than needed, I'm sure he can find another means of selection if jquery is not available.

Comment: There's a bug in your code, as it does not work for more than one `li.time`. This is better: `$('li.time > a').text( function () { return $(this).text().split(' ').reverse().join(' '); } );`.

Answer (score 0):

Old school JavaScript:

```
function replaceLinkText(className, newContents) {
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].className == className) {
      var a = items[i].getElementsByTagName('A'); 
      if (a[0]) a[0].innerHTML = newContents;
    }
  }
}

replaceLinkText("time", "Review Time");
```

Note that modern browsers support `getElementsByClassName()`, which could simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the DOM and modify the Text with the following JavaScript:

```
var li = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
   li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText = 'new text';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KFA58/