# Javascript - Selection Name Changing Problems

Tags: javascript, html

I asked another question ([Javascript - Link Name Changing with restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459831/javascript-link-name-changing-with-restrictions)) similar to this yesterday, but after trying to apply the same fix, nothing seemed to happen. Hopefully I can get some insight.

I applied the first solution:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, j = elements.length; i<j; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = "Time Review";
}
```

which worked great. However, on another piece of code, there is:

```
<div class='validatable' id='style_picker'> 
    <div class='selector'> 
        <span class='selection'></span> 
        <span class='handle'></span> 
    </div> 
    <ul type='none'> 
        <li class='time'> 
            <span class='style_item'></span> 
            <span class='copy'>time</span> 
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the *time* to show up as 'time review'. Once again, I only have the header/footers to work with for javascript, and I can't change any of the actual code myself. I'm a little confused as to why the aforementioned code doesn't change the text. Could anyone shed some light on this and/or provide a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It didnt work because the text you're trying to change is in a `<span>` tag now

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i = 0, j = elements.length; i<j; i++){
  elements[i].innerHTML = "Time Review";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Notice `getElementsByTagName("a")`, this will get tags: `<a>`, in the new version of your code, it's `<span>`, so replace "a" to "span".
If you just want to replace time to time review, just use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("copy")[0].innerHTML = "time review";
```